# How to reference nested object into other collection Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want to reference nested object exist in another Collection object, in my Event object so that when i get Event of User than Venue of Event shall retrieve with it, i am new in mongodb and spring can any one help to do this.

```
class User{
private String name;
private Venue venue;

//Getter and Setter 
}

class Event {
@DBRef
private Venue venue;

//Getter and Setter 
}
```

Comment: Can you give more details about your question? Maybe you can reread your question to check if you put every word to its place. It is difficult for me to understand. I can see the class User and the class Event. How are they related?

Comment: I've stumbled upon the same problem - having a nested object (Venue) with its own ObjectId and then DBreferencing it from another object (Event). Basically boils down to referencing a nested object and not one from a top-level collection.

Answer (score 2):

If each User has one Venue, you can reference User instead of Venue in Event. If a User may have more than one Venue, you better make Venues a seperate collection and reference both in User and Event.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class Venue{
    //Getter and Setter 
}

class User{
    private String name;
    @DBRef
    private Venue venue;

    //Getter and Setter 
}

class Event {
    @DBRef
    private Venue venue;

    //Getter and Setter 
}
```